# $http.post is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I am trying to submit a form data to an API endpoint which I created. I have tested it in **PostMan** and the API functions well and I can get the data in successfully. But while connecting that API endpoint to a function in angular js I get the following error.

[image]

**Heres my code:**

```
 $scope.saveSession = function() {

    $http.post("/session/survey", $scope.session).success(function(data, status) {
         $window.location.href = '/';

                console.log("Sucessfully getting data" + JSON.stringify(data));
    })
  }
```

**Note:**

`$scope.session` is an object that being populated by using the `ng-model` tag.
For example:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="session.title">
```

**Edit (Controller Code):**

```
// This is our controller for the bio page
var session = angular.module('session', ['sessionService'])

session.controller('sessionCtrl', function($scope, $http, $window, sessionServices) {

$scope.session = {};

$scope.saveSession = function() {

    $scope.session.sessionNo = 1;
    $scope.session.coach = "mmmm";
    $scope.session.modules = "wokr place";

    //console.log(user);
    $http.post("/session/survey", $scope.session).success(function(data, status) {
         $window.location.href = '/';
                console.log("Sucessfully getting added bio" + JSON.stringify(data));
    })
    };

 });
```

Comment: @Sajeetharan see updated question.

Answer (score 11):

That's because `.success()` really isn't a function. As [the documentation explains](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), a promise is returned by `$http.post()` which you can chain with `.then()`

```
$http.post('/someUrl', data, config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Answer (score 6):

Use promises, "success" function doesn't exists in $http object($http success and error methods are available only in older versions of Angular 1.x, but they've removed in Angular 1.6):

```
// Simple GET request example:
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
});
```

More in official documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Note that the $http `success` and `error` methods were available in older versions of Angular 1.x, but they've been deprecated for awhile and removed in Angular 1.6.  So you'll probably still see lots of old Angular code using the `success` function.  It's time to roll with the changes and switch to `.then`.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you're using `$http.post().success`.

Try;

```
$scope.saveSession = function() {

$http.post("/session/survey", $scope.session).then(function(data, status) {
     $window.location.href = '/';

            console.log("Sucessfully getting data" + JSON.stringify(data));
})
}
```

We use .then to return a "promise" from the $http service.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I just dealt with a similar issue with versions 1.7.2 and 1.7.4. It's not exactly the same issue because I was never using .success but I'm posting here because this post comes up first when searching.

When using the shortcut version $http.post(/api/endpoint/', data) I would get:

> "TypeError: $http.post is not a function"

And if I used it with the callbacks exactly as it appears in [the documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.4/docs/api/ng/service/$http#examples):

```
$http({method: 'POST', url: '/api/endpoint/', data: $scope.newObject}).then(function (response) {
    $scope.status = response.status;
    $scope.data = response.data;
}, function (response) {
    $scope.data = response.data || 'Request failed';
    $scope.status = response.status;
});
```

I was getting

> "TypeError:  $http(...).then is not a function"

**In this case the problem was that I had both $resource and $http in the same controller.** Not sure if this is the intended behavior but removing $resource suddenly made $http work again.

Hopefully this helps someone else